# Target specific li tag to change background color and text color

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am looking to target the last `li` in a `ul` in order to just change that specific `li`'s `color` and `background-color`

i.e. changing the `color` and `background-color` of  the specific `li` I want to change. This list is for a Dropdown navigation menu.

```
<ul class="site-nav">
    <li class=" ">
        <a href="/" class="current">
            <span>LIST ONE</span>       
        </a>    
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="" href="/list-nav-two"><span>LIST TWO</span></a>
        <ul class="site-nav-dropdown">
            <li><a href="#" class=""><span>SERIES 1</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class=""><span>SERIES 2</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class=""><span>SERIES 3</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class=""> <span>SERIES 4</span></a> </li>
            <li><a href="/current-equipment-list" class=""><span>THIS IS THE LI TO CHANGE</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a class="menu__moblie" href="/list-nav-three"><span>LIST THREE</a>
        <ul class="site-nav-dropdown">
            <li><a href="#" class=""><span>SERIES 1</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class=""><span>SERIES 2</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class=""><span>SERIES 3</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class=""> <span>SERIES 4</span></a> </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I thought of using:

```
ul .site-nav-dropdown li:nth-last-child(1) a {
    background-color: red;
    color: #fff;
}
```

But this highlights both bottom `li`s in list two and list three

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your selector to this to only addess the last `li` in the second submenu:

```
ul.site-nav > li:nth-child(2) ul.site-nav-dropdown li:last-child a
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```css
ul.site-nav > li:nth-child(2) ul.site-nav-dropdown li:last-child a {
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<ul class="site-nav">
  <li class=" ">
    <a href="/" class="current">
      <span>LIST ONE</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="" href="/list-nav-two"><span>LIST TWO</span></a>
    <ul class="site-nav-dropdown">
      <li><a href="#" class=""><span>SERIES 1</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class=""><span>SERIES 2</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class=""><span>SERIES 3</span></a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class=""> <span>SERIES 4</span></a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="/current-equipment-list" class=""><span>THIS IS THE LI TO CHANGE</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown"><a class="menu__moblie" href="/list-nav-three"><span>LIST THREE</a>
    <ul class="site-nav-dropdown">
      <li><a href="#" class=""><span>SERIES 1</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class=""><span>SERIES 2</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class=""><span>SERIES 3</span></a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class=""> <span>SERIES 4</span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```